# Compress image before uploading to Firebase

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-storage, image-compression

Before I was using MVVM architecture and Kotlin I done it like this in Java.

I am passing image Uri to Bitmap

Java code:

```
Bitmap actualImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(mImageUri));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
actualImage1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
byte[] finalImage = baos.toByteArray();
```

`getContentResolver()` is not recognized by Kotlin.

How to write this in Kotlin, again I have image uri that I want to pass to Bitmap

Comment: How `getContentResolver()` is not resolve its a method of `ContextWrapper` it should be available inside Activity Directly . Or other than Activity you have to have `Context`  to use it like `context.getContentResolver()`.

Comment: How to use it inside ViewModel? Or should I compress the images in Fragment and then pass it to ViewModel?

Comment: Pass the `getContentResolver()` as a method parameter inside `ViewModel` also do this task in a background thread . You can use kotlin coroutine for easy implementation for threading ..

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this in Kotlin

```
   val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            this.contentResolver,
                            selectedPhotoUri
                        )
```